# (OWA) Office Web application server show high CPU

Tags: load-balancing, owa, office-online-server

We have two OWA servers and one of them is showing high CPU. It remains constantly 99% to 100% it does not go down.

I red that I should check load balancing by browsing to the following url:
http://oa1/hosting/discovery

It returns the xml.

Any idea what I should do?

How can I check if load balancing is really working?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

from the image clearly the `Antimalware Software` is causing the issue on the server. You have to make sure that antivirus exclusion properly implemented on the server. [Check this](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/office_web_apps_server_2013_support_blog/2014/12/19/antivirus-and-intermittent-issues-viewing-documents-with-office-web-apps-2013/)

For loadbalancing, its depend upon you load balancer settings. If it detect high CPU and take the server from LB then you will not see the issue with routine work.